# OpenRtb bidder on Azure, is it real?

Tags: c#, azure, logging, statistics

We are trying to build an OpenRtb bidder on Azure env. We use redis instances that deployed on Linux VM to store real time data (tracking keys, requests/bidwins counts, etc). We use WebApi based website  (standard plan/large instances/scaling by performance) as the end-point. In webapi bidder controller we use async methods, all requests to DBs and redis also async. Json.net to ser/der json req/resp.

Currently we have issues with latency. We should have possibility to receive more then 10000 req per sec and latency should be <100ms.

Could some one to share experience with me? Is this tech stack good for building apps like rtb bidders. Currently I'm trying to find the best strategy to store request context (query, request body, headers, etc) for each request. So, I need the way to insert a lot of (>10000) big messages very fast. I'm thinking about:

1. storing to log files and copying them to HDFS and parsing by Hadoop MapReduce tasks ( HDInsight)
2. using some queue such as AzureQueue or ServiceBus or maybe RabbitMQ and send req messages to queue, and some services (self-made or such as LogStash) will receive them and store to some storage as well.

Maybe some one could show me directions how to optimize latency and performance, because currently we have issues with this. Maybe some basic pitfalls?

Comment: Can you Describe your workflow of your System. Like what happens from the time you receive a Bid Request to Responding back. in a bit more Detailed Manner.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. 
I have little experience with Azure, but building rtb bidders with high throughput and low latency can be tricky if you involve things like queues or any kind of IO. Use those only if necessary, and preferably out of the bid path. Cache everything or use a high speed in memory store (Aerospike, Couchbase, etc .. even redis if you're smart about it).
Async is great but careful with having too many threads to schedule. that can induce high latency, if you can use epoll, non blocking IO. 
I've build a bidder running on aws, with netty (async non blocking io on the jvm) wrapped on Twitter's Finagle (twitter RPC system), chronicle map as model caching and aerospike for data serving. We could handle 20k req/sec on one box of m4.2xlarge (8 cores/ 32 Go) with a 99 percentile tail latency of around 45 ms and 16 ms on average. 
You tend to read that you should onlyuse bare metal for bidders, but it's more about architecture that virtualisation or not.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with our implementation and actually we decided to check possible alternatives. We benchmarked different langs and libs.

```
source Yandex.Tank response per second(ubuntu vm 8 cores)
target ubuntu vm 8 cores
golang fast http 30k+
nginx 20k
golang http 20k-
haskell wai warp 15k+
clojure http-kit 15k-
node.js 7k
rust hyper 10k+
rust iron 10k-
fsharp suave.io 4k+ (best result ever for .net web servers)
asp.net 5 kestrel coreclr/mono ??? 400-
```

So after that we started to use golang + fasthttp + redis. Actually it was enought to handle 40k rps on a single instance with a 99 percentile less than 11 ms. Actually currently asp.net 5 shows good results in speed you could check [here](https://github.com/aspnet/benchmarks)